# My program that counts the number of times a character appears in a string does not work for 1 input I am trying. It works on all other ones

Tags: python

when I enter "n Monday" it gives me the right output but then when I try something like "n Nothing" it gives me an error saying 'num_occur' is not defined. How can I fix this code without using the for statement.

```
string = str(input("Enter a string that contains a character and a phrase:\n"))
character = string[0]
phrase = string[2:]
if character in phrase:
    num_occur = phrase.count(character)
print(f'The number of times character {character} appears in the phrase: {num_occur}')
if character not in phrase:
    print(f'The number of times character {character} appears in the phrase: 0')
```

I tried adding str() in the if statement but that did not do anything.

Comment: Remove the first `if` line.

Comment: If the character doesn't appear in the phrase, you never set `num_occur`. You don't need the `if` statement, `count()` will return `0` if the character doesn't appear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words: if it is **not** the case that `character in phrase`, then what should `num_occur` be equal to? In these cases, what do you expect the code to do? Specifically, what value do you think `num_occur` will have, and how will the code set that?

Comment: Alternately: where the code says `print(f'The number of times character {character} appears in the phrase: {num_occur}')` - should that happen always, or only `if character in string`? Therefore, should it be inside that `if` block, or outside? Is it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if character in phrase:
    num_occur = phrase.count(character)
    print(f'The number of times character {character} appears in the phrase: {num_occur}')
```

you need to tab in that print ...

Answer (score -1):

```
string = str(input("Enter a string that contains a character and a phrase:\n"))
character = string[0]
phrase = string[2:]
if character in phrase:
    num_occur = phrase.count(character)
    print(f'The number of times character {character} appears in the phrase: {num_occur}')
else:
    print(f'The number of times character {character} appears in the phrase: 0')
```